# How to set UIImageView's height equal to videoPreviewLayer in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, constraints

I have set up a video preview layer as so:

```
previewView.videoPreviewLayer.session = session
```

And I have an image I want to overlay on top of this camera view such that the overlay's height is the same as the camera view and the overlay maintains aspect ratio.

I've noticed that different devices (iPhone vs iPad) have different sized black bars on the top and bottom of the camera view so I've given up on specifying a constant for the overlay dimensions. How can I set the height dimensions of this UIImageView to be the same as the video viewport?

Comment: Use constraints? Presumably, you are using constraints for the `previewView`, so constrain your "overlay view" to the the `previewView`.

Comment: The problem is previewView is not the same size as the videoPreviewLayer because there are black bars above and below the videoPreviewLayer depending on aspect ratio while the previewView is always full screen.

Comment: Well then... either change your `previewView` to **not** use full screen, or... I assume you are setting the aspect ratio of the preview layer, so set the size/position of the overlay view the same way. If that's not obvious, then edit your post with some of the code you are using - try to create a [mre].